# merge each letter in string (orderly) into a new string

Tags: c

So, I'm still very new in C programming.
There is 3 strings with the same length.
str1="abc", str2="def", str3="ghi".
The output in the new string will be like "adgbehcfi".

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str1[32], str2[32], str3[32], s[32];
    int count, i, j=0;
    printf("Insert String 1:");
    scanf("%s", str1);
    printf("Insert String 2:");
    scanf("%s", str2);
    printf("Insert String 3:");
    scanf("%s", str3);
    for(count=0;str1[count]!='\0';count++);
    for(i=0;i<count;i++){
        str1[i]=s[j];
        str2[i]=s[j+1];
        str3[i]=s[j+1];
        j++;

    }
    printf("String:%s", s);
    return 0;
}
```

i tried to run this program, but when i try to display the new string, it won't come out. All help is deeply appriciated.

Comment: The code doesn't copy anything into `s`. Instead, it copies random stuff from `s` into the other strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(i=0, j = 0;j<count;i += 3, j++){
    s[i]   = str1[j];
    s[i+1] = str2[j];
    s[i+2] = str3[j];
}
s[i] = '\0';
printf("String:%s ", s);
```

This is what you want :) as a little challenge try to figure out how this works, it will help you understand what is going on. For SO community I will come back and edit the answer explaining what is this doing in about an hour.

Comment: thank you for your help.when i try to run the program, it only display "adg"

Comment: @AlexanderAubert see the update, instead of `i < count` it should be `j < count`.

Answer (score 0):

to clarify your issue. In c

```
str1[i]=s[j];
```

means

'copy the jth character from s and put it in the ith character of str1'

You mean the other way round

```
s[i]=str1[j];
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should check the size of destination string. This approach uses pointers, fewer operations, you might enjoy the comparison.

```
#include<stdio.h>

char*
strmerge3(char* s, char*str1, char*str2, char*str3)
//strmerge3(char* s, long slen, char*str1, char*str2, char*str3)
{
    if(!s) return(s); //handle NULL in string
    char *dp=s; //destination pointer
    char *p1=str1?str1:""; //source pointers
    char *p2=str2?str2:"";
    char *p3=str3?str3:"";
    //long len=0; //slen--; //save room for null terminator

    for( ; (*p1 | *p2 | *p3) ; ) {
        if(*p1) dp++ = p1++; //if(++len>len) break;
        if(*p2) dp++ = p2++; //if(++len>len) break;
        if(*p3) dp++ = p3++; //if(++len>len) break;
    }
    dp = '\0'; //null terminate dest, at end
    return(s);
}

int main(void)
{
    char str1[32], str2[32], str3[32], s[32*3];
    int count, i, j=0;
    printf("Insert String 1:");
    scanf("%s", str1);
    printf("Insert String 2:");
    scanf("%s", str2);
    printf("Insert String 3:");
    scanf("%s", str3);

    strmerge3(s,str1,str2,str3);
    //strmerge3(s,sizeof(s),str1,str2,str3); //you should pass s size

    printf("String:%s", s);
    return 0;
}
```